# I can't get Html.TextBoxFor value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a very interesting problem.

the control I use

```
 <input id="DOSYA_NO" name="DOSYA_NO" class="form-control" />
```

I can get the input value with the code below.

```
$("#gelenevrakFoto").click(function () {
    alert($('#DOSYA_NO').val());
  });
```

but this way the input value is empty.

```
$("#gelenevrakFoto").fileinput({
                    uploadUrl: "/Dosya/Upload?policeId=" + $('#POLICE_ID').val() + "&Kategori=GELENEVRAK&dosyaNo=" + $('#DOSYA_NO').val(),
                    maxFileCount: 10,
                    showBrowse: true,
                    browseOnZoneClick: true
                });
```

[image: Network Tracing]

Please I would like you to help on the subject. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `callback` function

> You can also set uploadUrl as a function callback which will return a
> string. In that case, the function will get executed at runtime just
> before every ajax call. This will enable you to set a dynamic upload
> url based on runtime / dynamic conditions.

https://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/plugin-options#uploadUrl

```
$("#gelenevrakFoto").fileinput({
  uploadUrl: function() {
    let params = {
      policeId: $('#POLICE_ID').val(),
      dosyaNo: $('#DOSYA_NO').val(),
      Kategori: 'GELENEVRAK'
    };
    return "/Dosya/Upload?" + $.param(params); // $.param for good practice
  },
  maxFileCount: 10,
  showBrowse: true,
  browseOnZoneClick: true
});
```